# WSTP simplifying expression from C

Tags: simplifying-expressions, mathlink-or-wstp

I am looking to simplify arbitrary algebraic expressions by invoking the mathematica kernel from C using WSTP. My initial attempt was the following, which was based on the online documentation and the example "factor.c"

```
algebra = "(a + a + a + a - b)";

WSPutFunction(lp, "EvaluatePacket", 1L);
WSPutFunction(lp, "FullSimplify", 1L);
WSPutString(lp, algebra);
WSEndPacket(lp);

WSFlush(lp);

while( (pkt = WSNextPacket(lp), pkt) && pkt != RETURNPKT ) {
    WSNewPacket(lp);
        if (WSError(lp)) {
            error(lp);
        }
}

const char *output;
if(! WSGetString(lp, &output)) {
    printf("Unable to read from link\n");
    return -1;
} else {
    printf("%s\n", output);
}
WSReleaseString(lp, symbol);

WSPutFunction(lp, "Exit", 0);
```

However, WSTP returns the still unsimplified expression from the WSGetString() call. I expected to see "4 a - b" as the result of "FullSimplify[(a + a + a + a - b)]".

I then attempted using EnterTextPacket and ReturnTextPacket but it isn't clear how these work.

My goal is to simplify algebraic expressions through WSTP. What is a working simple or common way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not evaluating

```
FullSimplify[(a + a + a + a - b)]
```

You are evaluating

```
FullSimplify["(a + a + a + a - b)"]
```

You used the PutString function.  It does exactly that: it puts a *string* on the link.

There are three options:

Either put the correct expression structure, which is

```
Plus[a, a, a, a, Times[-1, b]]
```

and would involve something like this (untested):

```c
MLPutFunction(lp, "Plus", 5);
  MLPutSymbol(lp, "a");
  MLPutSymbol(lp, "a");
  MLPutSymbol(lp, "a");
  MLPutSymbol(lp, "a");
  MLPutFunction(lp, "Times", 2);
    MLPutInteger(lp, -1);
    MLPutSymbol(lp, "b");
```

Or you can precede putting the string by `MLPutFunction(lp, "ToExpression", 1)`. This will send `ToExpression["(a + a + a + a - b)"]` instead of `"(a + a + a + a - b)"`.

Finally, you could use an `EnterTextPacket` instead of an `EvaluatePacket`.

Please read [this tutorial](http://edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf), especially section 2.  This document explains things much better than the documentation.

---

Additional comments:

- `FullSimplify` is not necessary to compute `a+a+a+a-b`.  The result would be the same as without `FullSimplify`
- You used `1L` in `WSPutFunction()`.  Its third argument is in fact of type `int` (and not `long`), thus using `1L` is not appropriate.